# Magento 2 setup gives 404 after version ugrade

Tags: magento2, upgrade, 404

I had upgraded my site's version from 2.4.0 to 2.4.3 but the web page shows 404 not found error after upgrading

[image]

I have added my project source in **"/var/www/html/php73/listermais"** can anyone please give me a solution for this? I have tried various solutions but my local setup is not working. I am using **ubuntu** system.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your project source

FROM:

**"/var/www/html/php73/listermais"**

TO:

**"/var/www/html/listermais"**.

Also, configure the base URLs and static URLs in your local database under table `core_config_data`.